# MotoG4 and MotoG4+ not able to pair Ble sensor with latest android update 7.0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola, android-7.0-nougat

- I am using moto G4 and plus, both device i updated with latest android version 7.0.
- After Updating latest OS Bluetooth pairing stopped. now i am not able to pair any sensor.
- From android side i checked while connecting ble device, i am getting successful connection response in **onConnectionStateChange**.
- Form that response i am calling discoverservices, but for that i am not getting any callback for long time.

  - same issue was there in android 7.0 release in Nexus but in latest 7.1.1 release issue is not there.

seems moto release latest update with bug. if any one have more info or solution regarding this issue then it will helpful for me.
Thanks

Comment: I guess it's a bug, but could you print the logcat output and check the Bluetooth hci snoop log? There might be info there what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, I am using Moto G4 Plus,
When the os version was 6.0.1 it was working file, but after i update to 7.0 My BLE device is not scanning but other devices are showing.

can you help in this?

Comment: @HardikChauhan according to me there is no solution you have to wait till next update come. 7.1 it is working for nexus